# Epson ET-2726 printer fails to respond

Tags: printer, troubleshooting, network-printer

I have an Epson ET-2726 printer that won't respond much.

1. If I try, for example, to go into Wi-Fi Setup Wizard I get the
   message "Printer busy. Please try again later".
2. Trying to print (Wi-Fi or wired) says the printer is not available.
3. If I turn it off at the power switch it says "Turning off" and stays with this on the display until I unplug it from the power
4. If I try and print a status sheet by going into Settings -> Print Status Sheet -> Configuration Status Sheet it displays the message "Starting up. Please wait" for a couple of seconds before returning to the Configuration Status Sheet screen. I do get a message about loading paper to start printing, but there is paper loaded, the tray is aligned correctly and I have had a look and can't see anything lodged inside.
5. If I try and do a restore by going into Settings -> Restore Default Settings -> Clear all data and settings. I click "OK" on "Restore all settings including network to default?" I get the "Starting up. Please wait" before being returned to the Restore Default Settings menu and it doesn't appear to have done anything

I have tried connecting to it on multiple devices with no joy (confirmed the devices I tried with have no stuck jobs), so it seems the printer thinks it is doing something that prevents me doing anything else with it even after having it switched off an unplugged for days.

Anyone seen this before and know how to fix it, or suggest any troubleshooting approaches? I am at a bit of a loss to even know where to start with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

With problems like this, I would try a factory reset. This will clear any random data that may be stuck in the printer's non-volatile memory. Before you do, print out a configuration page, so you can set the printer up again.

On the front panel, go to Settings > Restore Default Settings > Clear all data and settings.

Here's a [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DInRJVaexWk) with instructions.

Comment: Hi @hdhondt. I have tried this approach and updated my answer with additional detail as to the outcome of this. It doesn't appear to be going a restore and if I try and, for example, go through the Wi-Fi setup wizard after going through restore I still get "Printer busy. Please try again later". Could do with a way of forcing a hard reset, but can't way a way of doing something like this.

Comment: That's really strange. If the printer is still under warranty I would contact Epson. The manual is copyrighted 2019, so you may be lucky. Otherwise, if nobody else has any suggestions, it may be time to consider a new printer.